# No possibilities to validate an artifact modified of add comment

Tags: tuleap

In the new version of Tuleap 7.1, I notice on trackers when i want to add a comment from an artifact or want to modify a list field (combo box), it's not possible to validate the changes through a button as there is no button displayed.

When I try to create a new artifact, at the end of the page, I have the validation button but but this button is not present if I want modify my artefact or add a comment.

It is just possible to validate the changes done on a one line text field, in pressing enter key after the modification.

it's a real problem for us because we are currently unable to use trackers at the moment.  Can anyone suggest a fix or help in any way?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug about the validate button that don't display when we modify an artefect or add a comment.

For me, the problem exists on cent os 5.8 with php51 or php53.

the problem come from a ckeditor-4.3.2.js file missing in /usr/share/codendi/src/www/scripts

to resolve that, you have to copy and rename :

> cp /usr/share/ckeditor/ckeditor.js /usr/share/codendi/src/www/scripts/ckeditor-4.3.2.js

Next remove the codendi cache : (i'm not sure if it's very important, but let's do it anyway)

> rm /usr/share/codendi/src/www/scripts/combined/codendi*.js

And the bug is resolved, you will see to display the validate button.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the temporary js file.

```
rm /usr/share/tuleap/src/www/scripts/combined/codendi*.js
```

or

```
rm /usr/share/codendi/src/www/scripts/combined/codendi*.js
```

Comment: It doesn't work !!

I'm using the 5.1 PHP instead of 5.3 PHP. do you think it was the problem ? Tuleap is installed on CentOs 5.8.

Comment: Pretty sure 5.1 is no-longer supported for Tuleap > 7.0. I think there are instructions on how to update the version somewhere. Also, the only browsers supported are FF, chrome and IE > 9, I think.

Comment: I upgraded php51 to php53 and nothing changed, the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I went to see the php error log in /usr/share/codendi/src/www/scripts/error_log.

After to try to modify a field in an artefact. I had this error added in the log.

> [Mon Jun 16 11:34:52 2014] [error] [client ] File does not exist: >/usr/share/codendi/src/www/scripts/ckeditor-4.3.2
>
> [Mon Jun 16 11:34:55 2014] [error] [client ] File does not exist: >/usr/share/codendi/src/www/scripts/ckeditor-4.3.2

Maybe is it the problem why i can't validate the modification ?

I verified if this ckeditor-4.3.2 file exists, indeed it doesn't exist.

Where can I find this file ? What have I to install ?